# Split Models over Packages

Tags: django, django-models

Isn't it possible to have a package:

```
models
```

and then inside the model another package

```
models.country
```

and then syncdb it?

I always get an error, even when I import it in `__init__.py` inside the models package.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fine, but make sure you're setting the [`app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/options/#app-label) property on the models' `Meta` classes.